# Call ngModelChange even if the event is the same

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am having a dropdown list in which I use an array of objects.
My problem is that I want to call the function even if the event does not change.
But as far as I know, the `ngModelChange` fires up only when the value changes.

Is it a possibility to call the function every time an option is clicked?

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="model.cv_enum" (ngModelChange)="addPrivacy({enum:$event, model: model})" class="form-control-sm" id="cv-enum" name="cv-enum">
                <option *ngFor="let privacy of privacyActivity.privacyActivity" [selected]="privacy" [ngValue]="privacy.id" (change)="addPrivacy(privacy)">
                  {{ privacy.description}}
                </option>
              </select>


  addPrivacy(data:EditPrivacyDialog) {
    if(data.enum === Groups.Friends_except || data.enum === Groups.Specific_friends) {
      return this.dialog.open(PrivacyDialogComponent, {
        data,
        panelClass: 'my-class'
      })
    }
    this.model.cv_enum = data.enum;
    this.modelDataService.updateDate(this.model._id, this.model);
  }
```

Comment: You can find the list of `select` element events here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement. It doesn't appear that any of them will do as you want. There is also a `(click)` event which does generate on every click. But that will *also* generate a click when the user clicks on the drop down (not selecting an item).  You could instead build a list of buttons that would provide a notification on every click.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '(blur)' events, which I think makes sense

Comment: How to blur the events ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a quick example so you can understand

```html
<select  [(ngModel)]="books" (blur)="clickChange($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let item of arrOption" [value]="item.value">{{item.text}}</option>
</select>
```

```
books = ''
  clickChange(event:Event) {
    let a=event.target as HTMLSelectElement;
    console.log(a.value);
    console.log(this.books);
  }
```

It is not convenient for you to observe in the comments. I wrote it below